# Error with curl, --data-urlencode

Tags: json, curl, cmd

I need to send a get request from the command line. When you explicitly register a request, the request passes without errors.

> curl -G -k https://api-ip.fssprus.ru/api/v1.0/search/physical
>   --data-urlencode "region=0" --data-urlencode "lastname=Лутов" --data-urlencode "secondname=Владимирович" --data-urlencode "firstname=Андрей" --data-urlencode "token=Rxb7tDa5bPwZ"

but in this format I get an error.

> curl -G -k https://api-ip.fssprus.ru/api/v1.0 -d "@/test/test.JSON"

file test.JSON:

> --data-urlencode "token=Rxb7tDa5bPwZ"  --data-urlencode "region=0" --data-urlencode "firstname=Андрей" --data-urlencode "secondname=Владимирович" --data-urlencode "lastname=Лутов"
>   --data-urlencode "birthdate=10.05.1972"

tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Can you share the exact error?

Comment: @JishnunandPk error - 400 Bad request : Your browser sent an invalid request.